# Microsoft Remote Desktop stop working on Monterey 12.6

Tags: monterey, remote-desktop

As the title says, I've just updated to macOS 12.6. I used to log in to a Win box with Microsoft Remote Desktop 10.7.9. Now, I can't login anymor, but I get the error "user account did not work".

Tried on an old macOS with same settings and everything works fine. The problem seem on my macOS 12.6.

Here is the log:

```
E|2022-09-15 18:23:01.9250 +02:00|FileLoggingWindowController.swift:243 Logging to file started!!
E|2022-09-15 18:23:09.3540 +02:00|:0 {88c1211a-c2eb-492f-bc16-562a8b220000} <0x7000072c9000> "SSLBASE"(ERR): Caught a CredSSPProtocolException during handshake: The server reported error code -1073741715
    /Users/runner/work/1/s/source/stack/libtermsrv/rdp/LegacyXPlat/Filters/SSL/SslFilter.cpp(1753): OnHandshakeException()
E|2022-09-15 18:23:09.3540 +02:00|:0 {88c1211a-c2eb-492f-bc16-562a8b220000} <0x7000072c9000> "SSLBASE"(ERR): DoHandshake failed!
    /Users/runner/work/1/s/source/stack/libtermsrv/rdp/LegacyXPlat/Filters/SSL/SslFilter.cpp(1602): ContinueHandshake()
E|2022-09-15 18:23:09.3540 +02:00|:0 {88c1211a-c2eb-492f-bc16-562a8b220000} <0x7000072c9000> "SSLBASE"(ERR): ContinueHandshake failed! hr = 0xc000006d
    /Users/runner/work/1/s/source/stack/libtermsrv/rdp/LegacyXPlat/Filters/SSL/SslFilter.cpp(970): OnDataAvailable()
E|2022-09-15 18:23:09.3540 +02:00|:0 {88c1211a-c2eb-492f-bc16-562a8b220000} <0x7000072c9000> "SSLBASE"(ERR): Disconnecting due to SSL error 0x8!
    /Users/runner/work/1/s/source/stack/libtermsrv/rdp/LegacyXPlat/Filters/SSL/SslFilter.cpp(1055): OnDataAvailable()
E|2022-09-15 18:23:09.3540 +02:00|:0 {88c1211a-c2eb-492f-bc16-562a8b220000} <0x7000072c9000> "-legacy-"(ERR): Fail OnDataAvailable call
    /Users/runner/work/1/s/source/stack/libtermsrv/rdpplatform/uclient/ucore/prothandlerbase.cpp(795): OnDataAvailable()
E|2022-09-15 18:23:11.3300 +02:00|FileLoggingWindowController.swift:194 Logging to file finished!!
```

How can I fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logging in with the Microsoft account fixed the problem (using the password and not the pin).

Answer (score 1):

I’m using Version 10.7.9 of Microsoft Remote Desktop and on build 21G115 of macOS 12.6 with no issue for local accounts or domain accounts.

You might have some other issue at play with those SSL errors. Hard to tell as windows can be set up quite differently for RDC but I wanted you to know it wasn’t a blanket issue between the versions you posted.

My instinct is to check clocks on all machines and get them within a minute or two. Then look at the event log on the Windows side to correlate the logs between server and client.

It appears your first error is a user log on error - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/imstscaxevents-onlogonerror

> **STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE** (-1073741715 (0xC000006D))
> The attempted logon is not valid. This is due to either an incorrect user name or incorrect authentication information.

Comment: I see. The strange thing is that it works with another macOS (Catalina), another remote desktop version with the same account. I can't figure out how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Isn't there a support team to contact?

Comment: Microsoft support can be very good if you pay enough in licenses @floatingpurr

Comment: Logging in with the microsoft account fixed the problem